# How to make scripts run from anywhere on OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, path

I've correctly added my scripts folder to my $PATH. But I still cannot run the scripts from anywhere by simply calling them. How do I achieve this?

Example. If I have `~/scripts/` in my path and in `~/scripts/` I have `foo.sh` I want to be able to be anywhere and type `foo` and have it execute `foo.sh`. When I type `echo $PATH` I see my `scripts` folder correctly included in my path. I've also made `foo.sh` executable because if I `cd` to the `scripts` directory and type `foo.sh` it runs correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type in "`foo.sh`", you'll likely start your script up since the path to it is now included in your "`$PATH`" file.

Right now the shell simply doesn't know how to map "`foo`" to "`foo.sh`".

So maybe you just need to add an alias to your .tcshrc / .bashrc (e.g. "`alias foo foo.sh`") or an actual file symlink (e.g. "`ln -s foo foo.sh`") to your script and you'll be all set.

Comment: or just remove the `.sh` extension its not actually necessary

Comment: OK. So if I type `foo.sh` from anywhere it works but simply `foo` doesn't work. Prodigitalson how do you get it so you don't need to specify the file extension?

Comment: I offered you two possible solutions, Jesse.  Which one seems more straightforward to you?

Comment: It appears the only way to achieve what I want without declaring the file extension is to also set a symlink or an alias.

Comment: @JesseAtkinson I suspect you're coming from a Windows background, where you don't need to type the `.exe` part to run `foo.exe`, and Windows "knows" that files with certain extensions are executable. It does this because earlier versions of Windows did not have a file permissions/executable bit like OSX/Unix/Linux. Now that you're using OSX (which is BSD Unix under the hood), you'll just need to get used to the different system. You can name a file whatever you want, and as long as you set the `X` bit you can run it, but you need to enter its **full** name.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it should work, except for the part where you seem to want to alias foo to foo.sh.  Did you re-source your .profile, .bashrc, or wherever you made the change to PATH afterward?  Next you can add an alias from foo foo.sh.